# Why is this elixir function undefined

Tags: elixir

I have rebooted my learning of the Elixir language.  I am trying to try a variation of the Fizzbuzz problem with the following code.

```
defmodule FizzBuzz.Fb4a do

  def upto(n) when n > 0 do
    fizzbuzz(n)
  end

  defp toTuple(n), do: {n, ""}

  defp toString({v,a}) do
    if String.length(a) == 0 do v else a end
  end

  defp genFB(d, s) do
    fn ({v, a}) ->
      cond do
        rem(v, d) == 0 -> {v, a+s}
        true           -> {v, a}
      end
    end
  end

  # do3 = genFB(3, "Fizz")
  # do5 = genFB(5, "Buzz")
  # do7 = genFB(7, "Bang")

  defp fizzbuzz(n) do
    1..n
    |> Enum.map(&toTuple/1)
    # |> Enum.map(&do3/1)
    # |> Enum.map(&do5/1)
    # |> Enum.map(&do7/1)
    |> Enum.map(&toString/1)
  end

end
```

When I uncomment the `do3 = genFB(3, "Fizz")` line, I get the following error:

```
** (CompileError) lib/fib4a.ex:22: undefined function genFB/2
```

I do not understand how `genFB/2` can be undefined or not seen by the compiler.  I have obviously missed something very fundamental in the definition of functions somewhere.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Compilation stages

> I do not understand how `genFB/2` can be undefined or not seen by the compiler.

The main thing one should clearly understand about *Elixir*: it is, unlike many other languages, uses the same syntax for “metaprogramming” and the code itself. Being a compiled language that runs inside a VM, *Elixir* is unable to execute any arbitrary *code*. **The code must be compiled upfront.**

Compilation basically means converting the code into AST *and then* into BEAM.

The code that is found in the topmost scope (and inside `defmodule` macro) is being executed on the compilation stage. **It is not included into the resulting BEAM.** Consider the following example:

```rb
defmodule Test do
  IO.puts "️ Compilation stage!"

  def yo, do: IO.puts "⚡ Runtime!"
end

Test.yo
```

If you’ll try to compile this, you’ll see `"️ Compilation stage!"` printed *during compilation* only. There is no way to refer to this code from the resulting BEAM, because it’s simply discarded after execution during compilation.

OTOH, to get the `"⚡ Runtime!"` string printed, you need to explicitly run `Test.yo` in runtime.

That said, your `doN` variables (even if they were referring valid aka available / known to the compiler functions) are assigned as local variables during the compilation stage *and immediately discarded* because nobody uses them.

### Workaround 1

There are things that are available *inside* runtime functions:

- module attributes ([Docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Module.html#module-module-attributes), [Tutorial](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html))
- [macros](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html)

#### Module attributes

They are available because the compiler, when it sees a module attribute and/or macro, **injects the resulting AST inplace, without touching it.** Consider the following example:

```rb
defmodule Test do
  @mod_attr &IO.puts/1

  def yo, do: @mod_attr.("⚡ Runtime!")
end

Test.yo
```

Here we declared the module attribute, referencing function `IO.puts/1` *and* called it from runtime.

The function we reference *must be compiled at the moment it gets referenced*.

#### Macros

Consider the following example.

```rb
defmodule Test do
  defmacrop puts(what), do: IO.puts(what)

  def yo, do: puts("️ Compilation time!")
end
```

Wait, what? TheIt was printed *during the compilation stage!* Yes, it was. Macros inject the AST produced by their `do:` block, and therefore `IO.puts(what)` *was executed during the compilation stage*.

To fix this behaviour one should [`quote`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/quote-and-unquote.html) the content of the macro, to *inject it as is* instead of executing it.

```rb
defmodule Test do
  defmacrop puts(what), do: quote(do: IO.puts(unquote(what)))

  def yo, do: puts("⚡ Runtime!")
end

Test.yo
```

So, you might have fixed your code by introducing a cumbersome macro, injecting the call to real function, but I’d leave this out of scope of this answer. There is way more easy way to accomplish a task.

### Workaround 2

```rb
defmodule FizzBuzz.Fb4a do
  def upto(n) when n > 0, do: fizzbuzz(n)

  defp toTuple(n), do: {n, ""}

  defp toString({v, ""}), do: v
  defp toString({_v, a}), do: a

  defp genFB({v, a}, d, s) when rem(v, d) == 0, do: {v, a <> s}
  defp genFB({v, a}, _d, _s), do: {v, a}

  defp fizzbuzz(n) do
    1..n
    |> Enum.map(&toTuple/1)
    |> Enum.map(&genFB(&1, 3, "Fizz"))
    |> Enum.map(&genFB(&1, 5, "Bazz"))
    |> Enum.map(&genFB(&1, 7, "Bang"))
    |> Enum.map(&toString/1)
  end
end
```

I have cleaned up the code a bit to use pattern matching instead of imperative `if` and `cond` clauses.

In the first place, you don’t need to return a function. *Elixir* has a nifty feature allowing to capture functions with `&`. You might even assign the result of curried function to a variable and call it later, but it’s not really needed here.

If you still want to assign the intermediate variables, make sure the module the function belongs to *is already compiled*.

```rb
defmodule FizzBuzz.Fb4a do
  defmodule Gen do
    def genFB({v, a}, d, s) when rem(v, d) == 0, do: {v, a <> s}
    def genFB({v, a}, _d, _s), do: {v, a}
  end

  def upto(n) when n > 0, do: fizzbuzz(n)

  defp toTuple(n), do: {n, ""}

  defp toString({v, ""}), do: v
  defp toString({_v, a}), do: a

  defmacrop do3, do: quote(do: &Gen.genFB(&1, 3, "Fizz"))
  defmacrop do5, do: quote(do: &Gen.genFB(&1, 5, "Bazz"))
  defmacrop do7, do: quote(do: &Gen.genFB(&1, 7, "Bang"))

  defp fizzbuzz(n) do
    1..n
    |> Enum.map(&toTuple/1)
    |> Enum.map(do3())
    |> Enum.map(do5())
    |> Enum.map(do7())
    |> Enum.map(&toString/1)
  end
end
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @AlekseiMatiushkin.  There is a lot to consider here.  I was, indeed, trying for something like a partially applied, curried function but was starting with a function that created and returned a function (HOF).  My attempt to store the returned function in a variable at the module level - that I could then use in a function - was what was giving me fits.  I had no idea that the compiler was just throwing away my module-level variables.  I like your workaround 2 and it is similar to something I also came up with.  I will have to study your workaround 3.

Answer (score 2):

> I do not understand how genFB/2 can be undefined or not seen by the
>   compiler. I have obviously missed something very fundamental in the
>   definition of functions somewhere. What have I missed?

This example doesn't work either:

```
defmodule My do
  def greet do
    IO.puts "hello"
  end

  greet()
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

** (CompileError) my.exs:6: undefined function greet/0
```

Same error here:

```
defmodule My do
  def greet do
    IO.puts "hello"
  end

  My.greet()
end
```

The reason is that defining a function doesn't introduce a name into the module scope, and you are calling the function at the module scope (for some unexplained reason).

> **Named Functions And Modules**
>
> ...named functions have a couple of peculiarities.
>
> First, defining a named function does not introduce a new binding into
>   the current scope:
>
> ```
> defmodule M do
>   def foo, do: "hi"
>
>   foo()  # will cause CompileError: undefined function foo/0
> end
> ```
>
> Second, named functions cannot directly access [the] surrounding scope.

[Scoping Rules in Elixir](https://elixir-lang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical/scoping.html#scoping-rules-in-elixir-and-erlang)

That fact that def's don't create a name in the module scope should make you wonder how they can be called inside another function.

> The answer to this lies in the following rule followed by Elixir when
>   trying to resolve an identifier to its value:
>
> Any unbound identifier is treated as a local function call.

Huh?  Translation: you can't call defs in the module scope--that's just the way it is!

> I have rebooted my learning of the Elixir language.

You can execute statements in an .exs file like this:

```
defmodule My do
  def greet do
    IO.puts "hello"
  end

end

My.greet()  #<====  This will execute
```

---

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

hello   #<=== Output
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)>
```

But if `greet/0` is private (`defp`), you can't even do that.

(Why do you name modules `FizzBuzz.Fb4a` which makes it as irritating as possible to type?  What's the matter with the name `F4`?)

**Edit:** it looks to me like `defmodule` creates the following scopes:

```
defmodule My do
  x = 100

  def greet do
    x = 1
  end

  def go do
    x = 3
  end
end

  ||
  VV

+----MyModuleScope-------+ 
|                        |
|    x = 100             |  
|                        |
|    +--greetScope-+     |      +--Invisible Scope--+
|    |   x = 1    -|-----|----->|       greet       |
|    +-------------+     |      |       go          |
|                        |      +-------------------+
|    +--goScope----+     |               ^    
|    |   x = 3    -|-----|---------------+
|    +-------------+     |
|                        |
+------------------------+
```

You can see that the module scope is not accessible by inner scopes here:

```
defmodule My do
  x = 10

  def greet do
    IO.puts(x) 

  end

end

My.greet()
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

warning: variable "x" is unused
  my.exs:2

warning: variable "x" does not exist and is being expanded to "x()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  my.exs:5

** (CompileError) my.exs:5: undefined function x/0
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1338: :lists.foreach/2
    my.exs:1: (file)
```

The last part is an error saying x is undefined.  But, there is a way to access the values in the module scope:

```
defmodule My do
  x = 10

  def greet do
    x = 1
    IO.puts(unquote(x)) 
    x
  end

end

My.greet()
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex my.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

10
Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)>
```

However, `unquote()` is a macro  so I think that result is just a compiler trick, which doesn't have anything to do with runtime, i.e. you aren't looking up values in an outer scope, the compiler just inlined the values in your code at compile time.

Comment: Thanks.  I have read "Elixir in Action" (Manning) and am in the middle of "Programming Elixir >= 1.6" (PragProg).  So far, neither of them have mentioned these scoping rules.  As for the module names, I am coming from a very different environment and just fall back on previous learning.  This isn't for production purposes, obviously, but for separating several different implementations for learning purposes.  I will pick up on the "accepted" practices as I go, I assume.

Comment: *I have read "Elixir in Action" (Manning) and am in the middle of "Programming Elixir >= 1.6" (PragProg).*  I've got it the other way around. *neither of them have mentioned these scoping rules.*  Nope, but every language has peculiarities that reveal themselves along the learning curve. :)

Comment: Thanks again.  So the same scoping rules prevent using the `do3`, `do5`, and `do7` functions in the pipeline as well.  If the anonymous functions are bound to a variable in the current module you cannot use the bound variable in that module to call the function?

Comment: @melston, I added a drawing to my post of the scopes that I think are created.  Usually the inner scopes can see the values of the outer scopes, however that's not true for the module scope.  To access the module scope you have to write `unquote(varname)`.  `unquote()` effectively says jump into the module scope and lookup the variable.

Comment: Yeah.  I saw the diagram.  I am still not familiar with unquote or what it does.  I have the impression it is used in macros which I am also unfamiliar with as yet.

Comment: @melston, Due to the way it works in this case, you can think of `unquote()` as a function named `get_module_scope_var(varname)`.

Comment: I am sorry, but this answer is _very_ inaccurate if not wrong. _“you can't call defs in the module scope—that's just the way it is!”_ —sure you can. The reason of why it’s failing here is the difference between _compilation stage_ and _runtime_. Elixir is a compiled language, running inside Erlang VM. Elixir _compiles and executes_ all the code on topmost level _during compilation stage_. For the function to be available to the ErlangVM, the code must be compiled. And the Elixir compilation unit is a module. That is the only reason `genFB` is not available: it’s module is not yet compiled.

Comment: **That is not a scoping issue, that is a compilation error.** At the moment when _the compiler_ encounters a call to `genFB`, it knows nothing about this function. It tries to look up an internal ETS containing the list of the available funcitons (that said: already compiled,) finds nothing and raises.

Comment: I don't understand, @AlekseiMatiushkin.  It sounds like this means that you can't call any functions from a module inside the module because the module isn't compiled yet.  But that doesn't match what I see in other cases.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, *the Elixir compilation unit is a module. That is the only reason genFB is not available: it’s module is not yet compiled*--Ah.  *“you can't call defs in the module scope—that's just the way it is!” —sure you can.*-- Do you have an example? *I am sorry, but this answer is very inaccurate if not wrong.* -- So, post an accurate answer.  I've edited my post, therefore the op can take away the checkmark.

Comment: Well, I took away the checkmark but I am not sure where that leaves me.  It would appear that trying to assign a value to a variable at the module level by calling a function defined in that module is not possible.  This is unfortunate.  It isn't a showstopper but it means I have to find a different way to organize my modules for my purposes.

Comment: @melston Assigning a value to a variable on the module level makes a little sense: _it will be compiled and **executed** during compilation stage_. The code _won’t go into the compiled module_. If you want a one-time-run, do it _outside of the module_, on the very top level, when the module is already compiled. Also, I did not want this answer to be unmarked as correct, I just wanted it to be updated to mention the only reason: the difference between compilation stage and runtime. I will post the detailed answer in a couple of hours.

Comment: _“Do you have an example?”_ —sure, any function from any already compiled module is welcome to be called from any scope.

Comment: @melston, *I have read "Elixir in Action" (Manning) and am in the middle of "Programming Elixir >= 1.6" (PragProg). So far, neither of them have mentioned these scoping rules.* --  On p. 36 in "Elixir in Action >= 1.6", it says, "...modules define a scope for local variables, but these are accessible only at the top level of that module, and not in functions defined in the module."

Comment: You are right, @7stud.  I completely missed that comment